# Multilevel Column Pivot

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I am Learning Python using pandas, I do not know, how to pivot a data frame with columns with a multilevel index. I have the following pivot table :

```
df= df.pivot_table(index=["FECHA",'Planta'],
                              aggfunc = {'Menor_F0' :np.sum, 'Menor_fc' :np.sum,
                              "Total_Muestras " : "count"
                              })
```

it gives: PD: it is correct

```
                Menor_F0  Menor_fc  Total_Muestras 
FECHA   Planta                                                         
01/2014 455            0         0               2 
        470            1         2               5
01/2016 455            0         0               1     
        470            0         1               2
```

But I want to visualize it, in this form, how can I do it?

```
FECHA         01/2014                                           01/2016
         Menor_F0  Menor_fc  Total_Muestras     Menor_F0  Menor_fc  Total_Muestras
PLANTA  
455         0         0               2           0         0               1  
470         1         2               5           0         1               2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `stack` and `unstack`:

```
df.stack().unstack(level=(0,2))
```